# Loin de(s) cris et de(s) jurons, retentissant même la nuit dans notre quartier

Tags: articles

> J’ai préféré dormir à la belle étoile, loin **de** cris et **de** jurons,
> retentissant même la nuit dans notre quartier.
>
> J’ai préféré dormir à la belle étoile, loin **des** cris et **des** jurons,
> retentissant même la nuit dans notre quartier.

Est-ce que ces cris et ces jurons sont définis ici ? Autrement dit, est-ce qu'il faut employer l'article défini devant ces mots ? D'une part, j'en parle pour la première fois, donc il faudrait utiliser l'article indéfini. De l'autre, j'en parle en général, donc il faudrait utiliser l'article défini.

P.S. Je connais la règle *de + des = de* et *de + les = des*...

Answer (score 3):

On utilise le pluriel: *Loin "de les" cris*. Ces cris et ces jurons sont définis, ce sont ceux dont on est loin.

On retrouve le même *loin des* dans la locution bien connue :

> [Loin des yeux, loin du cœur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/loin_des_yeux,_loin_du_c%C5%93ur).